# Mutable Live Data clear and recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-mvvm

I have a fragment in android studio for displaying some results searched through a searchview; the data is taken otherafter an API call with retrofit. Next show them through a recyclerview. My problem is that whenever I search for a word with searchview the results I searched for before remain and are not replaced or deleted. how can I do?

SearchFragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchview);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            performSearch(query);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
private void performSearch(String query) {

    fragmentRicercaBinding.resultsTextView.setText(query);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
            new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    gamesRecyclerViewAdapter = new GamesRecyclerViewAdapter(gamesList,
            requireActivity().getApplication(),
            new GamesRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGamesItemClick(Games games) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFavoriteButtonPressed(int position) {
                    gamesList.get(position).setFavorite(!gamesList.get(position).isFavorite());
                    viewModel.updateGames(gamesList.get(position));
                }
            });
    fragmentRicercaBinding.resultRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    fragmentRicercaBinding.resultRecycler.setAdapter(gamesRecyclerViewAdapter);

    String lastUpdate = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    fragmentRicercaBinding.resultProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    viewModel.getResultGames(query, Long.parseLong(lastUpdate)).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            result -> {
                if (result.isSuccess()) {

                    GamesApiResponse gamesApiResponse = ((Result.GamesResponseSuccess) result).getData();
                    List<Games> fetchedGames = gamesApiResponse.getResults();

                    if (!viewModel.isLoading()) {
                        if (viewModel.isFirstLoading()) {
                            gamesList.clear();
                            viewModel.setTotalResults(((GamesApiResponse) gamesApiResponse).getNumber_of_total_results());
                            viewModel.setFirstLoading(false);
                            gamesList.addAll(fetchedGames);

                            gamesRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0,
                                    gamesList.size());
                        } else {

                            gamesList.clear();
                            gamesList.addAll(fetchedGames);
                            gamesRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0, fetchedGames.size());
                        }
                        fragmentRicercaBinding.resultProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        viewModel.setLoading(false);
                        viewModel.setCurrentResults(gamesList.size());

                        int initialSize = gamesList.size();

                        for (int i = 0; i < gamesList.size(); i++) {
                            if (gamesList.get(i) == null) {
                                gamesList.remove(gamesList.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        int startIndex = (viewModel.getOffset()*TOP_HEADLINES_PAGE_SIZE_VALUE) -
                                TOP_HEADLINES_PAGE_SIZE_VALUE;
                        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(startIndex));
                        for (int i = startIndex; i < fetchedGames.size(); i++) {
                            gamesList.add(fetchedGames.get(i));
                        }
                        gamesRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(initialSize, gamesList.size());

                    }
                } else {
                    ErrorMessagesUtil errorMessagesUtil =
                            new ErrorMessagesUtil(requireActivity().getApplication());
                    fragmentRicercaBinding.resultProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

    fragmentRicercaBinding.resultRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            boolean isConnected = isConnected();

            if (isConnected && totalItemCount != viewModel.getTotalResults()) {

                totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();


                if (totalItemCount == visibleItemCount ||
                        (totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + threshold) &&
                                dy > 0 &&
                                !viewModel.isLoading()
                        ) &&
                                viewModel.getResultsGamesLiveData().getValue() != null &&
                                viewModel.getCurrentResults() != viewModel.getTotalResults()
                ) {
                    MutableLiveData<Result> gamesLiveData = viewModel.getResultsGamesLiveData();

                    if (gamesLiveData.getValue() != null &&
                            gamesLiveData.getValue().isSuccess()) {

                        viewModel.setLoading(true);
                        gamesList.add(null);
                        gamesRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(gamesList.size(),
                                gamesList.size() + 1);


                        int page = viewModel.getOffset() + 1;
                        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(page));
                        viewModel.setOffset(page);
                        viewModel.resultGames(query);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

recyclerview:

```
package com.example.gameslist.adapter;

import android.app.Application;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.gameslist.R;
import com.example.gameslist.model.Games;

import java.util.List;

public class GamesRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int GAMES_VIEW = 0;
private static final int LOADING_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onGamesItemClick(Games games);
    void onFavoriteButtonPressed(int position);
}

private List<Games> gamesList;
private final Application application;
private final OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public GamesRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Games> gamesList, Application application,
                                OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.gamesList = gamesList;
    this.application = application;
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (gamesList.get(position) == null) {
        return LOADING_VIEW_TYPE;
    } else {
        return GAMES_VIEW;
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;

    if (viewType == GAMES_VIEW) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.games_item, parent, false);
        return new GamesViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.loading, parent, false);
        return new LoadingGamesViewHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof GamesViewHolder) {
        ((GamesViewHolder) holder).bind(gamesList.get(position));
    } else if (holder instanceof LoadingGamesViewHolder) {
        ((LoadingGamesViewHolder) holder).activate();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (gamesList != null) {
        return gamesList.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

public class GamesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private final ImageView imageViewCover;
    public GamesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void bind(Games games) {
        String imag2 = String.valueOf(games.getImage());
        Glide.with(application)
                .load(imag2)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_circle_down_24)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageViewCover);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.imageview_favorite) {
            //setImageViewFavoriteGames(!gamesList.get(getAdapterPosition()).isFavorite());
            onItemClickListener.onFavoriteButtonPressed(getAdapterPosition());
        } else {
            onItemClickListener.onGamesItemClick(gamesList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        }
    }
}

public static class LoadingGamesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ProgressBar progressBar;

    LoadingGamesViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_loading);
    }

    public void activate() {
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}
```

}